# How to export a 3D object from blender to adobe after effects

Tags: export

How can I export a 3D object from blender to adobe after effects without using cinema 4D. And in what format?

Comment: this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M5hkUhQ1sU4 suggests you can use *.3DS , *.DAE , *.KMZ , *.U3D , *.OBJ  in AE 5.5. Obj is easy to export form Blender.

Answer (score 2):

Bartek Skorupa has an addon that lets you export objects and camera to an AE script that you can run in AE to recreate the scene.

http://cg.bartekskorupa.com/b2ae/

[image]