# Export Null/Empty position/rotation/scale data to After Effects

Tags: objects, export

Is there a way to export a null's position/rot/scale data from an animation and use it later for comping in After Effects?

Thanks

Comment: What is "*null position data*" and what is "*AE*", could you clarify?

Comment: Thought of that too, but wanted to be sure. No idea about the other though, maybe some camera tracking data perhaps?

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It is After Effects, obviously.
Null position data would be exactly what it looks like, though. Not sure how to describe it properly.

Ex. In Cinema 4D you can export a null's position/rot/scale data from an animation, and use it later for comping in AE.

Thx for the comments, btw

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) to clarify your question.

Comment: There is an addon that is included as part of blender. It needs to be enabled in the user preferences (I don't know if it still works on current versions) https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/Adobe_After_Effects The webpage is here: http://cg.bartekskorupa.com/b2ae/

Comment: @cegaton Thanks a bunch! 
Will check it out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to export a 3D object from blender to adobe after effects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53803/how-to-export-a-3d-object-from-blender-to-adobe-after-effects) and [Exporting Motion Tracking Data from Blender to After Effects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42566/exporting-motion-tracking-data-from-blender-to-after-effects)